# Как в Flutter сделать адаптивное приложение?

Tags: flutter, dart

Можно ли сделать адаптивное приложение во Flutter? 
Например , один код написал , чтоб на больших и маленьких экранах получилось одинаково.
Или есть какой нибудь пакет для этого?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter из коробки имеет адаптивный UI, так как разрабатывается как мульти-платформенное решение (для всего где есть экран и возможность для взаимодействия). Вы лишь можете улучшить эту функцию, под ваши нужды.

---

[Разработка для разных размеров экрана и ориентаций.](https://medium.com/flutter-community/developing-for-multiple-screen-sizes-and-orientations-in-flutter-fragments-in-flutter-a4c51b849434)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.